# Can '-ing' form replace 'to infinitive' in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, usage

Here are three sentences. A) and B) are okay, but what about C)?

I want to know if C) is also possible.

> A) My blister made it a problem to walk.
>   B) My blister made walking a problem.
>
> C) My blister made it a problem walking.(?)

Comment: Yes, you can often replace the infinitive with the gerund.

Comment: Yes, and be aware you now have a **noun**.

Answer (score 1):

B is more natural.

Direct object ("walking") followed by a noun as object compliment ("a problem") is a common pattern. The other two, although grammatically not incorrect, sound quite counterintuitive.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes

All three are understandable and not incorrect.

- A sounds somewhat stilted.
- B sounds fine.
- C also sounds somewhat stilted.